# How to access Flash global security settings on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, flash, osx-mountain-lion

To access the settings manager, I followed the instructions [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html).

`System Preferences -> Other -> Flash Player`

Now I want to access the [global security settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html), in order to enable Flash to run on my local filesystem. But this tab or menu doesn't appear in the Settings Manager. All I see is four tabs,

`Storage, Camera and Mic, Playback, Advanced`

How do I access the global security settings?

Answer (score 1):

The `System Preference` pane for Flash is actually where you make global settings.  So for filesystem access, find it under the `Storage` tab.   If you right-click on Flash content, you'll get a menu that has the Flash context menu.  Selecting the `Global Settings...` item will bring you to the `System Preference` pane;  the `Settings...` item will modify the settings for that particular site.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not working. In "Local storage settings by site", I added `file://*` and `file://` with `Storage Access: Allow`, but I still can't see Flash content from my local filesystem.

Comment: Such as an .flv file in your web browser?  There once was a fee plugin for Quicktime called Perian that allowed one to do that, but it is no longer being developed.  The folks at http://perian.org have put up suggestions for alternatives.  You can look for Flash players/plugins on the App Store too.

Comment: No, it's actually Flash embedded in an HTML file, accessed via a JavaScript API. http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/tutorial